Why does swagger in tab 1 crash when selecting a file upload in another tab that is a react app?
So I created a simple file upload for my website to test some things. I have a asp.net core web api. When starting the server it opens a swagger tab. And when I start my react app it opens another tab. Now when selecting a file in the input something happens that crashes the swagger tab or the whole browser (I have no clue) resulting in the api to stop. I don't see visually anything happen, no tabs are closed and the file selection works. The logs of my react app and browser are clear. I use Brave as browser.
The react app website
My code of my react app
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const baseurl = "https://localhost:7010/api";
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const changeFile = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }
    setFile(file);
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    if (!file) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    try {
      axios
        .post(`${baseurl}/files`, {
          talentId: "1",
          fileName: file.name,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          axios
            .put(response.data.sasToken, file, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": file.type,
                "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
              },
            })
            .then(() => {
              axios.post(`${baseurl}/files/confirm`, {
                talentId: "1",
                fileName: file.name,
              });
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Upload pdf</label>
      {/* A popup to ask for the file and upload, when succesfull it sets the text beneath the label to the filename */}
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept=".pdf" onChange={changeFile} />
        <button onSubmit={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


When I seperate the 2 tabs into their own browser window, nothing happens. Swagger doesn't crash so the api stays up. So I think it has to do with the react app.
(EDIT)
I switched default browser to edge and the problem is solved. Please still answer if you know how to fix it for Brave as browser.
